# how to call function if fetched data from database is != "Detained"

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I fetched the data from my database and echoed it. Once I go to a prisoner's profile and his status is not = detained, the button 'Add Visitor' should be automatically disabled.

Where should I put my disable() function for it to be called?

Here's my script

```
<script language = "javascript" type = 'text/javascript'>
function disable(){

            if(document.getElementById('prisonerstatus').value == "Detained"){
            document.getElementById("visitorbtn").disabled= false;}
            else{
                document.getElementById("visitorbtn").disabled= true;
            }

    };
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$idd =$_GET['id'];
$result = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM prisoner 
                            INNER JOIN offensedata ON prisoner.prisoner_id = offensedata.prisoner_id
                            INNER JOIN arrestdata on prisoner.prisoner_id = arrestdata.prisoner_id 
                            INNER JOIN booking ON prisoner.prisoner_id = booking.prisoner_id
                            WHERE prisoner.prisoner_id = $idd") or die($connect->error);

$rows1 = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows1 as $row){

$status = $row['status'];

echo "<input type = 'hidden' value = '$status' id = 'prisonerstatus'/>";

            echo "<div class='col-lg-3'>Status: $status </div>";
}
```

Here's my button

```
<input type = "button" class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;margin-top:1%;" value = "Add Visitor" id = 'visitorbtn'>
```

Please excuse my code. This is for my school project only, these codes are what have been taught to us. I will study on how to avoid SQL injections and apply it soon. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can call the function just after your HTML is processed in PHP.

Comment: or just not display the button at all, by doing the check in PHP

Comment: We don’t see all your ˋHTMLˋ code... but try it when loading the page and you could also try ˋIFFE ´ Immediately invoked function expression. A search in google for ˋIFEE ´ would help you

Comment: @k.vincent - Shouldn't it be `IIFE`? :-)

Comment: I don't need to submit since I just want my button to be disabled if a prisoner status != detained so that I could not be able to open the modal, modal in which I add visitor details if the status is = detained.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: yes, you‘re right... my bad. IIFE

Comment: The simplest solution would be to not printing the button at all if the status is detained. Should work with a simple `if`-statement.

Comment: Ok I will try it @MagnusEriksson

Comment: It worked. Thank you @MagnusEriksson How do I mark my question as answered?

Comment: You can create an answer yourself where you explain what you did and then mark that as accepted.